# Прямоугольник с закругленными углами (xml, shape)

Tags: java, android

Можно ли программно сделать прямоугольник, у которого закруглить все углы кроме одного? Знаю, как сделать прямоугольник со всеми закругленными углами, но можно ли как-то сделать что бы один угол был не закругленным?

Для всех закругленных углов использую:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#1eb8c6" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

А нужно прямоугольник, который бы выглядел вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#1eb8c6" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```